# TypeError: categories.map is not a function in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I've got this error:

> TypeError: categories.map is not a function

This is `App.js`:

```
export default function Header() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
           const loadCategories = async () => {
               let res = await API.get(endpoints['categories'])
               setCategories(res.data)
           } 

           loadCategories()
    }, []);

    return (
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">ECoursesAPP</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Trang chủ</Link>
                    {categories.map(c => <Link className="nav-link" to="#link">{c.name}</Link>)}
                </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
}
```

This is `API.js`:

```
import axios from "axios";

export let endpoints = {
    "categories": "/categories/"
}
    
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000"
})
```

Comment: COnsole the value of `res.data` and check if its an array or not.

Answer (score 1):

At the first render, your `categories` array is an empty array. So you are doing something like this:

```
[].map(item => <p>{item.name}</p>)
```

when there is no item in the array, using dot notation to get the item value will cause an issue.

There are two options for you:

1. add a default value at initializing phase on `setState`, for example:

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([
  {id: 0, name: "" , ...}
]);
```

2. wait for the API response before rendering the `categories`:

```
{
  categories.length > 0 && categories.map(
    // rest of the codes ...
  )
}
```

##### Update

there is another issue with your `api.js`

In Javascript objects, no need to wrap the `key` with the quotation marks. so remove it from `categories`:

```
let endpoints = {
    categories : "/categories/"
}
```

Comment: 2 way error not show but still can not get data from backend

Comment: I've updated my answer right now, please take a look @HuyNguyen

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a null check before .map to avoid run-time errors

```
{(categories || []).map(c => <Link className="nav-link" to="#link">{c.name}</Link>)}
```

Comment: It show TypeError: (categories || []).map is not a function

Comment: Can u console the value of categories?

Comment: show console:
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data: {count: 3, next: 'http://localhost:8000/categories/?page=2', previous: null, results: Array(2)}
headers: {content-length: '175', content-type: 'application/json'}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Ya. So whats the output of it?

Comment: And have output data from backend : data:
count: 3
next: "http://localhost:8000/categories/?page=2"
previous: null
results: Array(2)
0: {id: 3, name: 'Đồ họa'}
1: {id: 2, name: 'Lập trình hướng đối tượng'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object

Answer (score 0):

probably your api end point does not return an array so you can fix that or you can use categories?.map

Answer (score 0):

Hey According to your error the issue is array not show element at first time rendering so you use the logic if array exist then array map the data let i show you

```
    export default function Header() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
           const loadCategories = async () => {
               let res = await API.get(endpoints['categories'])
               setCategories(res.data)

       } 

       loadCategories()
}, []);

return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">ECoursesAPP</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Trang chủ</Link>
                {categories && categories.map(c => <Link className="nav-link" to="#link">{c.name}</Link>)}
            </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
    </Navbar>
)
```

}

Comment: It still error ,

Comment: are you sure your backend work fine?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/categories/ check return something?

Comment: localhost:8000/categories it return json array of category

Comment: I delete this line :REST_FRAMEWORK { 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination', 'PAGE_SIZE': '2',} in setting backend to fix this error